# « J'attends (de) tes nouvelles ? »

Tags: grammaire, articles

Est-ce qu'on dit :

> J'attends tes nouvelles.

ou

> J'attends de tes nouvelles.

Il me semble que *de tes nouvelles* est plus fréquent (selon Google), mais je trouve *de* + *adjectif possessif* un peu bizarre dans ce contexte. Comment expliquer ça ?

Comment: Les deux peuvent se dire, le sens est différent.

Comment: L'expression courante est "j'attends de tes nouvelles", mais à dire pourquoi...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On peut dire les deux. La première possibilité est utilisée pour signifier que l'on attends des informations sur une situation spécifique qui intéresse les personne en communication l'une avec l'autre. La seconde est une tournure idiomatique qui est utilisée pour parler de ce qu'une personne peut raconter de sa propre vie au moment où elle communique sans qu'un sujet spécifique soit escompté quant à propos de quoi celui/celle qui donne de ses nouvelles parle, sauf qu'il doit parler de sa propre vie et de ce qui l'entoure. S'il s'agit d'un homme qui est au Japon par exemple et qui écrit à sa femme, il pourra dans la communication qui constitue « ses nouvelles » inclure des anecdotes concernant la vie au Japon.

Dans les deux cas l'expression qui correspond dans le sens de faire ce qui est demandé (attendu) utilise le verbe « donner », mais dans le second seulement « donner » est idiomatique ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=envoie+de+mes+nouvelles%2Cte+donne+de+mes+nouvelles&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cte%20donne%20de%20mes%20nouvelles%3B%2Cc0)).

- Je te donne/envoie/fais parvenir/… **des**  nouvelles dans quelques jours si rien ne se passe.
- Je te donnerai **de mes** nouvelles dans quelques jours.

Answer (score 4):

J'attends tes nouvelles : les nouvelles viendront de la personne à qui on dit ça.

J'attends de tes nouvelles : les nouvelles de la personne à qui on dit ça peuvent être envoyées par quelqu'un d'autre.

Answer (score 3):

"Attendre des nouvelles de quelqu'un" a un sens un peu idiomatique, mais de manière générale, un *de* partitif peut s'adjoindre à plusieurs déterminants, y-compris les possessifs:

- il peint de ces merveilles
- elle s'est adressée à de ces gens
- j'ai goûté de tes pâtes
- j'ai ramené de leur pain

Avec un déterminant démonstratif, le sens partitif est assez peu évident (l'expression veut dire "un tel type de gens/de merveilles et marque le nom comme exceptionnel ou extrême dans sa catégorie).

Avec un déterminant possessif, par contre, le sens est purement partitif: une certaine quantité de tes pâtes/de leur pain.

Answer (score 2):

> Il y a une différence de sens entre les deux possibilités de la question :
>
> – J’attends tes nouvelles : cela signifie que j’attends que la personne en face me fasse part de nouvelles informations (recueillies ou des nouvelles à propos de quelque chose ou quelqu’un), ou encore qu’elle envoie des nouvelles (littéraires).
>
> – J’attends DE tes nouvelles : cela signifie que j’attends que la personne en face me donne de ses nouvelles (sa santé, sa vie, etc.).

Source : https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/en-attendant-de-tes-nouvelles/

Comment: D'accord sur le sens mais pas avec l'exemple précis choisit. Le fait de dire la personne en face de moi est trop spécifique et il me semble plus exact de dire « la personne à laquelle je m'adresse » car elle peut être en face de moi, mais aussi à l'autre bout du monde au téléphone ou devant son clavier.

Answer (score 2):

Cela dépend aussi de la personne à qui on s'adresse.

Si la personne est écrivain, la phrase « J'attends tes nouvelles » signifiera « J'attends que tu m'envoies les [nouvelles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouvelle) que tu as écrites ». L'autre version continuera de signifier ce que les autres réponses ont expliqué.